# Find distance between a circle's point and line AB, where A and B are it's tangents' intersections?

Tags: geometry, circles

Problem statement: Circle's point M is away from tangents A and B by 4 and 9 cm. Find how far away M is from a line AB.

My attempt: First I have drawn out the problem. Denoted x as the value that I need to find: [image: Circle]

I know only a few facts about inscribed triangles and one of them is the formula $S=\frac{abc}{4r}$. However it does not seem to be useful in this case as I don't really need a, b, c, r, nor S. I don't have the needed information to find them as well.

One thought that occurred to me was that I might accomplish something by searching for angles and then using sines' theorem. Problem - I don't know where to start.

Another idea that I got was to look at the fact that the problem points out how A and B are tangent lines. So, they make up right angle with the radius. Not sure where to go from there...

Comment: Your figure does not match the wording! The distance from $M$ to the tangent is by definition the distance from $M$ to the orthogonal projection of $M$ onto that tangent.

Comment: Your title question, which is utterly different from you body question, is unanswerable.  As is the question in the body.  Simply draw different circle.  On a very large circle M will be close to AB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the corrected figure (see @Mercy King above), with MC = 4 perpendicular to the tangent at A, and MD= 9 perpendicular to the tangent at B, join MA and MB, and draw ME perpendicular to AB.  Since triangles ACM and MEB are similar (see Euclid, *Elements* III, 32), $4/AM = ME/MB$.  And since triangles AME and BMD are likewise similar, $AM/ME = MB/9$.  Therefore, $4/ME = ME/9$, making $ME^2 = 36$ and $ME = 6$.

Comment: Where is C? Could you perhaps provide a drawing?

Comment: @Jens- C is on the tangent through A. MC = 4 is perpendicular to AC.  D is on the tangent through B.  MD = 9 is perpendicular to BD.  Still learning how to draw my own figures.

Comment: You've convinced me. Well done!

Comment: With your permission, I can add a picture to your answer.

Comment: @Mick- Thank you, please do.